# How to sort a list in one sheet while maintaining references in a separate sheet

Tags: excel

I need to update a numbered list in a master sheet (column A) and have it automatically fill column A in a second, slave sheet. In the second sheet, data relating to each of the numbers is manually entered into column B.

The problem is, if I sort column A in the master sheet, only column A is modified in the slave, and column B remains the same, meaning that column B is now referencing the wrong information.

Here is an image:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqO8s.png)

Is there any way of ensuring that all columns in the slave sheet are updated correctly and not just column A? I thought this would be quite straightforward but I'm coming up short.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Highlight all the cells you need and use `sort` like this

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQpxT.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqkz2.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GYIj.png)

I used `z-a`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this solution involves sorting data in the slave sheet - I can only sort the master sheet and the slave needs to update automatically.